# QT QSortFilterProxyModel item priority - make item always atop

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have QTreeView with custom model (based on QAbstractTableModel) and custom proxy model (based on QSortFilterProxyModel).
works fine but I need make some items always atop.

here is some pseudocode to explain what I need (how i think):

```
bool MyItemsProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    MyItemsModel *sm = (MyItemsModel*)sourceModel();
    MyItem *mleft = sm->host(left);
    MyItem *mright = sm->host(right);

    if(mleft->prio() == prioUp) && mright->prio() == prioUp){
        // return 0;
    }else if(mleft->prio() == prioUp) {
        // return reverse value?
    }else if( mright->prio() == prioUp){
        // return reverse value?
    }

    return QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(left, right);
}
```

QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan returns only boolean value, how i can implement triple logic (-1\0\1) in Qt sorting model?

update. fix by:

```
if(mleft->prio() == prioUp) && mright->prio() == prioUp){
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(left, right);
}else if(mleft->prio() == prioUp) {
    return (this->sortOrder() == Qt::AscendingOrder)
}else if( mright->prio() == prioUp){
    return !(this->sortOrder() == Qt::AscendingOrder)
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I have a similar problem. It seems like lessThan doesn't compare against all items in the widget.

Comment: code in update works for me